# Can I deploy .net core 3.1 and .net framework sites on IIS 8.5 at the same time?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, iis-8

Does ASPNetCoreModuleV2 interfere with request handling for Framework apps too? Since the default for .Net Core is InProcess hosting, how does it affect existing .net framework applications if IIS is hosting combination of sites(separate app pools)?

Comment: Did you try? This is a problem solving platform...

Comment: yes I did but didn't seem to function correctly. Got errors relating to aspnetcorev2 module. Although it was installed as part of hosting bundle and it pretty much brought down IIS for everything else too

Comment: Show the actual errors please. The actual error page contains enough information to troubleshoot.

Comment: My .net core 3.1 app works but framework apps fail with 503. 
Event log shows these errors:
1. Windows cannot access the file  for one of the following reasons: the storage drivers installed on this computer; or the disk is missing
Program: IIS Worker Process
2. Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 8.5.9600.16384, time stamp: 0x52157ba0
Faulting module name: aspnetcorev2.dll, version: 13.1.19350.1

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have installed a proper version of the .net framework on the server. Also, tie the correct application pool to your applications respectively.

**For .net framework application**, your application pool should set the .NET CLR version to .NET CLR Version v4.0.3.319. Pick "Integrated" in "Managed pipeline mode" for modern version of .net framework application.

**For .net core application**, set .NET CLR version to "No Managed Code" and leave the "Managed pipeline mode" with "Integrated".

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you definitely can host both .net framework and .net core websites on the same IIS instance.

Steps:

1. Host .NET Framework website on IIS. They are supported by default.
2. Follow the official manual to host your .NET Core website https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Can you please list the steps you followed to make this work? Thanks!